# What does the \u{...} notation mean in UNICODE and why are only some characters displayed like this in the CLDR project?

Tags: unicode

In [this link](https://unicode-org.github.io/cldr-staging/charts/37/by_type/core_data.alphabetic_information.html) you will find the most used characters for each language. Why are some characters in some languages displayed under the \u{...} notation?
I think that what is in the brackets is the hexadecimal code of the character, but I can't understand why they would only do it with some characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **character sequences enclosed in curly brackets** `{}` are digraphs (trigraphs, …) counted as a distinct letter in given language (supposedly with its own place in the alphabet), for instance

- [digraph {ch}](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digraph_(orthography)#Other_languages_using_the_Latin_alphabet) in `cs` (Czech language);
- [trigraph {dzs}](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_dzs) in `hu` (Hungarian alphabet);
- more complex digraph examples in `kkj` (*Kako* language) shows the following Python code snippet:

```
>>> kkj='[a á à â {a\u0327} b ɓ c d ɗ {ɗy} e é è ê ɛ {ɛ\u0301} {ɛ\u0300} {ɛ\u0302} {ɛ\u0327} f g {gb} {gw} h i í ì î {i\u0327} j k {kp} {kw} l m {mb} n {nd} ǌ {ny} ŋ {ŋg} {ŋgb} {ŋgw} o ó ò ô ɔ {ɔ\u0301} {ɔ\u0300} {ɔ\u0302} {ɔ\u0327} p r s t u ú ù û {u\u0327} v w y]'
>>> print( kkj)
[a á à â {a̧} b ɓ c d ɗ {ɗy} e é è ê ɛ {ɛ́} {ɛ̀} {ɛ̂} {ɛ̧} f g {gb} {gw} h i í ì î {i̧} j k {kp} {kw} l m {mb} n {nd} ǌ {ny} ŋ {ŋg} {ŋgb} {ŋgw} o ó ò ô ɔ {ɔ́} {ɔ̀} {ɔ̂} {ɔ̧} p r s t u ú ù û {u̧} v w y]
>>>
```

For instance, `{a\u0327}` renders as `{a̧}` i.e. something like *Latin Small Letter A with Combining Cedilla* which has no Unicode equivalent. A counterexample:

`ņ` (U+0146) *Latin Small Letter N With Cedilla* with decomposition `004E 0327`:

```
>>> import unicodedata
>>> print( 'ņ', unicodedata.normalize('NFC','{n\u0327}'))
ņ {ņ}
```

### Edit:

**Characters presented as unicode literals** (`\uxxxx` = a character with 16-bit hex value `xxxx`) are **unrenderable** ones (or **hard to render**, at least). The following Python script shows some of them ([Bidi_Class Values](https://www.unicode.org/reports/tr44/#Bidi_Class_Values) `L`-*Left_To_Right*, `R`-*Right_To_Left*, `NSM`-*Nonspacing_Mark*, `BN`-*Boundary_Neutral*):

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import unicodedata
pa = 'ੱੰ਼੍ੁੂੇੈੋੌ'
pa = '\u0327 \u0A71 \u0A70 \u0A3C ੦ ੧ ੨ ੩ ੪ ੫ ੬ ੭ ੮ ੯ ੴ ੳ ਉ ਊ ਓ ਅ ਆ ਐ ਔ ੲ ਇ ਈ ਏ ਸ {ਸ\u0A3C} ਹ ਕ ਖ {ਖ\u0A3C} ਗ {ਗ\u0A3C} ਘ ਙ ਚ ਛ ਜ {ਜ\u0A3C} ਝ ਞ ਟ ਠ ਡ ਢ ਣ ਤ ਥ ਦ ਧ ਨ ਪ ਫ {ਫ\u0A3C} ਬ ਭ ਮ ਯ ਰ ਲ ਵ ੜ \u0A4D ਾ ਿ ੀ \u0A41 \u0A42 \u0A47 \u0A48 \u0A4B \u0A4C'
pa = '\u0300 \u0301 \u0302 \u1DC6 \u1DC7 \u0A71 \u0A70 \u0A3C \u0A4D \u0A41 \u0A42 \u0A47 \u0A48 \u0A4B \u0A4C \u05B7 \u05B8 \u05BF \u200C \u200D \u200E \u200F \u064B \u064C \u064E \u064F \u0650'
# above examples from ·kkj· ·bas· ·pa· ·yi· ·kn· ·ur· ·mzn·
print( pa )
for chr in pa:
  if chr != ' ':
    if chr == '{' or chr == '}':
      print( chr )
    else: 
      print( '\\u%04x' % ord(chr), chr,
        unicodedata.category(chr),
        unicodedata.bidirectional(chr) + '\t',
        str( unicodedata.combining(chr)) + '\t',
        unicodedata.name(chr, '?') )
```

**Result**: `.\SO\63659122.py`

> ```
> ̀ ́ ̂ ᷆ ᷇ ੱ ੰ ਼ ੍ ੁ ੂ ੇ ੈ ੋ ੌ ַ ָ ֿ ‌ ‍ ‎ ‏ ً ٌ َ ُ ِ
> \u0300 ̀ Mn NSM  230     COMBINING GRAVE ACCENT
> \u0301 ́ Mn NSM  230     COMBINING ACUTE ACCENT
> \u0302 ̂ Mn NSM  230     COMBINING CIRCUMFLEX ACCENT
> \u1dc6 ᷆ Mn NSM  230     COMBINING MACRON-GRAVE
> \u1dc7 ᷇ Mn NSM  230     COMBINING ACUTE-MACRON
> \u0a71 ੱ Mn NSM  0       GURMUKHI ADDAK
> \u0a70 ੰ Mn NSM  0       GURMUKHI TIPPI
> \u0a3c ਼ Mn NSM  7       GURMUKHI SIGN NUKTA
> \u0a4d ੍ Mn NSM  9       GURMUKHI SIGN VIRAMA
> \u0a41 ੁ Mn NSM  0       GURMUKHI VOWEL SIGN U
> \u0a42 ੂ Mn NSM  0       GURMUKHI VOWEL SIGN UU
> \u0a47 ੇ Mn NSM  0       GURMUKHI VOWEL SIGN EE
> \u0a48 ੈ Mn NSM  0       GURMUKHI VOWEL SIGN AI
> \u0a4b ੋ Mn NSM  0       GURMUKHI VOWEL SIGN OO
> \u0a4c ੌ Mn NSM  0       GURMUKHI VOWEL SIGN AU
> \u05b7 ַ Mn NSM  17      HEBREW POINT PATAH
> \u05b8 ָ Mn NSM  18      HEBREW POINT QAMATS
> \u05bf ֿ Mn NSM  23      HEBREW POINT RAFE
> \u200c ‌ Cf BN   0       ZERO WIDTH NON-JOINER
> \u200d ‍ Cf BN   0       ZERO WIDTH JOINER
> \u200e ‎ Cf L    0       LEFT-TO-RIGHT MARK
> \u200f ‏ Cf R    0       RIGHT-TO-LEFT MARK
> \u064b ً Mn NSM  27      ARABIC FATHATAN
> \u064c ٌ Mn NSM  28      ARABIC DAMMATAN
> \u064e َ Mn NSM  30      ARABIC FATHA
> \u064f ُ Mn NSM  31      ARABIC DAMMA
> \u0650 ِ Mn NSM  32      ARABIC KASRA
> ```

Comment: I also thought about that possibility. However, note that sometimes characters with the notation \ u {...} appear alone, for example in the fifth row, the language "pa". I do not understand why.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like all codepoints that don't have a well-defined stand-alone look (or are not *meant* to be used as stand-alone characters) are represented with this notation.

For example [U+0A3C](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0a3c/index.htm) is present in the "character" `{ਫ\u0A3C}`. U+0A3C is a combining codepoint that modifies the one that is before it.

Comment: I also thought about that possibility. However, note that sometimes characters with the notation \ u {...} appear alone, for example in the fifth row, the language "pa". I do not understand why.

Comment: Look at [the info about this codepoint](https://www.compart.com/de/unicode/U+0A71). It is also a combining character, meaning it's meant to modify something else. I can't say I'm enough of an expert to understand why that's a character in that language, that's a question for linguists.